# React Native - JS has only made partial progress to catch up to UIKit

Tags: react-native

Within my application I have a NavigationIOS component that pushes new views. After navigating back quickly I hit the error "JS has only made partial progress to catch up to UIKit".

The code is block is:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Views/RCTNavigator.m#L487-L496

[image: The View]

How can I debug / resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too for now i'm waiting for the bugfix from facebook.

I share my code on GIT

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/65

```
BOOL jsGettingtooSlow =
  //    --- previously not caught up --------          ------- no longer caught up ----------
  viewControllerCount < previousReactCount && currentReactCount < previousReactCount;

  BOOL reactPushOne = jsGettingAhead && currentReactCount == previousReactCount + 1;
  BOOL reactPopN = jsGettingAhead && currentReactCount < previousReactCount;


  // We can actually recover from this situation, but it would be nice to know
  // when this error happens. This simply means that JS hasn't caught up to a
  // back navigation before progressing. It's likely a bug in the JS code that
  // catches up/schedules navigations.
  if (!(jsGettingAhead ||
        jsCatchingUp ||
        jsMakingNoProgressButNeedsToCatchUp ||
        jsMakingNoProgressAndDoesntNeedTo || 
        jsGettingtooSlow)) {
    RCTLogError(@"JS has only made partial progress to catch up to UIKit");
  }
```